# Is there a way to configure all files in a folder using a particular software?

Tags: sound, directory, convert, extract

Im using **openSMILE** software to extract features from an audio file. My work involves extracting mfcc featues from a **.WAV** file (to obtain a **.mfcc** file).

Default code to convert the file is as follows:

```
./SMILExtract -C config/MFCC12_E_D_A.conf -I input.wav -O output.mfcc.htk
```

this step involves converting one file at a time.

Is there a way to convert all the files in a folder simultaneously?

I have to convert some 2500 files. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following command in your terminal:

```
for f in $(ls -1 *.wav);do SMILExtract -C config/MFCC12_E_D_A.conf -I $f -O $f.mfcc.htk ; done;
```

You can see more looping constructs in this [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs).

Comment: its showing that it is unable to open the.wav file which isnt even in the folder

Comment: You should adapt your paths. The general patern is **for each file that comes from ls -1 _your-path_/*.wav;do _your-command_ ;done;**